# Resgatar dado de checkbox armazenado no banco

Tags: html, ajax, checkbox

Estou gravando dados de 6 checkboxes no banco. Estou tratando cada uma separadamente, como abaixo:

```
              <tr>
              <td>Tabela Nutricional:</td>
              <td><input type="checkbox" name="export_tabela[1]" id="export_tabela[1]" value="PORTUGUES"> Português
                  <input type="checkbox" name="export_tabela[2]" id="export_tabela[2]" value="INGLES"> Inglês
                  <input type="checkbox" name="export_tabela[3]" id="export_tabela[3]" value="ESPANHOL"> Espanhol
                  <input type="checkbox" name="export_tabela[4]" id="export_tabela[4]" value="FRANCES"> Francês
                  <input type="checkbox" name="export_tabela[5]" id="export_tabela[5]" value="ARABE"> Árabe
                  <input type="checkbox" name="export_tabela[6]" id="export_tabela[6]" value="COREANO"> Coreano</td>
              </tr>
```

Consigo gravar todos que foram marcados na página de cadastro e na tabela fica corretamente:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Meu problema é que na hora de resgatar os dados usando Ajax, ele não marca nenhum valor nos checkbox da página de edição, cujo HTML é igual ao da página de cadastro. O Ajax que uso, mostrado abaixo, grava corretamente em todos outros campos, pega a id e grava o valor:

```js
       // Verifica se foi concluído com sucesso e a conexão fechada (readyState=4)
        if (xmlreq.readyState == 4) {
            // Verifica se o arquivo foi encontrado com sucesso
            if (xmlreq.status == 200) {
                //Se o retorno foi vazio do MySQL
                if (xmlreq.responseText == "") {
                    document.getElementById("projeto").focus();
                    alert("Não existe o projeto informado!");
                    ids.forEach(function (id) {
                        document.getElementById(id).value = '';
                        document.getElementById("projeto").value = '';
                    });
                //Se encontrou dados
                } else {
                    //Aqui recebe os dados do processa.php, abre e aplica nos campos desejados
                    var dados = JSON.parse(xmlreq.responseText);
                    // função para preencher os campos com os dados
                    ids.forEach(function (id) {
                        document.getElementById(id).value = dados[id];
                    });
                }
            } else {
                result.innerHTML = "Erro: " + xmlreq.statusText;
            }
        }
```

Alguma sugestão de como posso trazer os campos e marcá-los na página de atualização?

Comment: Acho que em vêz de `.value` queres usar `.checked` que é a propriedade que marca/desmarca. Como vêm esse valor da base de dados e depois do JSON parse? vem como string ou Booleano? Se fôr booleano basta usares: `document.getElementById(id).checked = dados[id];`

Comment: Os dados vão para o ajax como array. Vc diz editar o ajax no momento da "carga" dos valores?

Comment: Pelo que li na pergunta a parte de enviar para a BD quais foram selecionados funciona, mas estás com problemas em marcar/desmarcar quando queres montar essa informação de novo com dados da BD, certo? nesse caso depende de como gravas na BD e como retornas via ajax. Se guardas os estado `checked`/`not checked` como string ou como Boolean?

Comment: Exato, a gravação está ok, meu problema é no retorno. Na verdade não gravei o estado, gravei o valor do campo: <input type="checkbox" name="export_tabela[1]" id="export_tabela[1]" value="PORTUGUES">. Como gravo o estado?

Comment: Depende de como envias para o servidor. Se envias com um formulário para o PHP só as que estão marcadas são passadas com o form. Se fôr por ajax tens de verificar o `input.checked` e excluir as que não forem marcadas, Se fôr o primeiro caso então podes simplesmente fazer `.checked = true;` para as que estiverem na base de dados, ou seja no JSON que veio do servidor.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda @Sergio, usei a tua sugestão do .checked, dividi a forma de resgatar os dados e funcionou. Obrigado.

Comment: De nada. Juntei uma resposta mais completa e uma sugestão de optimização.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvido editando o ajax:
Declarei as ids do checkbox separadamente:

```
    var ids2 = ["export_dizeres[1]", "export_dizeres[2]", "export_dizeres[3]","export_dizeres[4]", "export_dizeres[5]", "export_dizeres[6]", "export_tabela[1]", "export_tabela[2]", "export_tabela[3]",
           "export_tabela[4]", "export_tabela[5]", "export_tabela[6]"];
```

Depois, na hora de carregar os dados, usei a sugestão do @Sergio:

```
                    ids2.forEach(function (id2) {
                    document.getElementById(id2).checked = dados[id2];
                });
```

Obrigado pela ajuda.

Answer (score 2):

Para marcar uma checkbox precisas de dar um valor booleano à propriedade `checked` do elemento.

Como estás a usar uma `<form>` para enviar os dados originais para o PHP então somente as checkbox marcadas vão ser enviadas, o que significa que na hora de restaurar esse estado podes marcar como `.checked = true;` todos os que fizerem parte desse JSON.

Podes então fazer assim no teu loop:

```
var dados = JSON.parse(xmlreq.responseText);
// função para preencher os campos com os dados
ids.forEach(function (id) {
    document.getElementById(id).checked = true;
    document.getElementById(id).value = dados[id];
});
```

Porém podes optimizar este código se já tiveres um objeto com esses IDs, assim evitas usar `getElementById` ou `querySelector` excessivamente como no exemplo em cima. Seria algo como:

```
// quando a página carrega fazes cache desses elementos
var checkboxes = {};
["export_dizeres[1]", "export_dizeres[2]", "export_dizeres[3]","export_dizeres[4]", "export_dizeres[5]", "export_dizeres[6]", "export_tabela[1]", "export_tabela[2]", "export_tabela[3]", "export_tabela[4]", "export_tabela[5]", "export_tabela[6]"].forEach(function(id){
    checkboxes[id] = document.getElementById(id);
});

// e depois dentro do ajax basta fazer:

var dados = JSON.parse(xmlreq.responseText);
// função para preencher os campos com os dados
ids.forEach(function (id) {
    checkboxes[id].checked = true;
    checkboxes[id].value = dados[id]; // caso queiras também setar o valor
});
```